# Spring First Layer and Second layer autowiring

Tags: spring

I have a scenario wherein my ServiceImpl and Business Class implements the same interface. But im unable to autowire both of them.

```
   @RestController
   @RequestMapping("/myservice")
   public interface myInterface{

     @RequestMapping(value="/getSomething/{input}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
       doSomething(String input);

   }
```

Now i have two classes which implements same interface

```
@Component
@Qualifier("doSomethingImpl")
public class DoSomethingImpl implements myInterface{

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("businessLayer")
    myInterface businessLayer;

   doSomething(@PathVariable String input){
   //my logic here
   }

}

@Component
@Qualifier("businessLayer")
public class BusinessLayer implements myInterface{


   doSomething(@PathVariable String input){
   //my logic here
   }

}
```

Now when i run it on server i'm getting following error

> Cannot map handler 'DoSomethingImpl' to URL path
>   [/myservice/getSomething/{input}]: There is already handler of type
>   [class com.mypackage.business.BusinessLayer] mapped.

Could someone please help me to resolve this error

Comment: As noted, this isn't a wiring issue, but you should almost never be implementing the same interface at multiple levels, since the meaning of the method calls is usually different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that both controllers are being mapped to the same path. I suggest you change your code to something like:

```
   public interface myInterface{

       @RequestMapping(value="/getSomething/{input}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
       public Whatever doSomething(String input) {
          //whatever
       }

   }

@RequestMapping("something")
@RestController
public class DoSomethingImpl implements myInterface{

}

@RequestMapping("somethingElse")
@RestController
public class BusinessLayer implements myInterface{

}
```

Comment: DoSomethingImpl is the service layer where all my request mapping will be implemented. Business layer is for business logic which will have same set of methods. In that case how do i Autowire my business layer to call from DoSomethingImpl.

Comment: If `DoSomethingImpl` is a service, it should not be a `RestController` and should not implement the interface.

Comment: yes it makes sense to have the request mapping on Impl class. Its my mistake... thanks anyways its working now.